# When the first derivative is increasing slower or faster

Tags: derivatives

This problem is the 3rd question from the GRE practice book (ets.org) [here](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf)
What is the explanation of the answer (C)[image]

Answer (score 1):

From $x=0$ to $x=2$, the slope is positive.  Thus, $f(0)<f(2)$.

From $x=2$ to $x=4$, the slope is negative.  Thus, $f(2)>f(4)$.

The area under the $f'(x)$ curve from $x=0$ to $x=2$ is greater than the area from $x=2$ to $x=4$.  Thus, $f(0)<f(4)$.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer... You must integrate and use the area.

Answer (score 0):

At $f'(2)$ and $f'(4)$ the derivative is $ 0.$ So $f(2), f(4)$ must be a turning point or point of inflection.

Now we also see at $x < 2, f'(x)$ must be positive, and at $2 < x < 4, f'(x)$ is negative .

Hence $f(2)$ is a (local) maximum, and $f(2)$ must hold the highest value.

To order $f(0)$ and $f(4)$, we simply see that the slope/derivative is much bigger towards $f(0)$ than towards $f(4)$, so $f(0)$ reaches a lower value quicker than $f(4)$) and  hence $f(4) > f(0)$.

All in all, we have:

$f(0) < f(4) < f(2)$